# run copy file script in python 27 get path error errno22 in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, encode, windows-task-scheduler

When I run a script in Windows Task Scheduler, I got

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:
'\\172.16.60.16\\\xf1\xee\xba\xcf\\lantian\\FAC\\FAC\xbb\xe3\xd7\xdc\xca\xfd\xbe\xdd\xd4\xb4\\F17\xba\xc5\xbb\xfa\xcc\xa8\xd2\xec\xb3\xa3\xbc\xc7\xc2\xbc\xb1\xed.csv
```

but I run it in IDLE and console was fine. code down there:

```
record_dir = r"D:\Record"
target_dir = r"\\172.16.60.16\耦合\lantian\FAC\FAC汇总数据源"
file_path = os.path.join(record_dir, filename)
target_path = os.path.join(target_dir, filename)
shutil.copyfile(file_path, target_path)
```

Is it an encoding problem?

I've tried to convert target_path to unicode, but that doesn't work, either.

Comment: use a encoding comment header like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (utf8 won't be the proper coding here probably)

Comment: i have write `#_*_ coding:gb2312 _*_` in header,when i use utf8,the error message of the path became utf8 format string

Comment: check if you can't use python 3. Management of encoding is way better in python 3. not sure the coding comment works in python 2 either

Comment: as a general case, avoid all non-ascii characters in name...

Comment: thanks a lot,i am trying to using python 3 to do this task.i have some other way to do this job,but i just wonder how this problem happened.just curiosity

Answer (score 0):

In this condition,it was the path of share which somehow can't access by Windows task scheduler.So i use `net use \\172.16.60.16\耦合` every time  before i copy file to this share to get this script can access this share.And finally,it works.
FYI:
in my script the code like this:

```py
delete_drive_cmd = r"net use * /DEL /Y"
create_drive_cmd = r"net use \\172.16.60.16\耦合 /PERSISTENT:NO"
os.system(delete_drive_cmd)
os.system(create_drive_cmd)
```

and here is the website where i get answer:
"https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe/scheduled-task-wont-run-bat-file?forum=winservermanager"

Answer (score -1):

The "r" removes the double "\" before the ip address you are trying to access.
Try to debug the issue using os.path.exists() on the folder you are writing to.

Comment: double `\\\` is UNC prefix. And the program works in IDLE, must be an encoding issue

Comment: it works in IDLE and windows console,once i run it in Windows Task Scheduler,it went wrong,but it went well in other machine which has the same system config